# MongoDB join or lookup via nested/sub document field

Tags: mongodb

I have variety of events, and hourly statistics of receiving that event.
I would like to merge both of them using $lookup. Please help me, on how do to that on nested document where event_id is my common field to lookup.

```
Events:
{
  "event_id"      : "1",     //Unique
  "event_name"    : "name1",
  "severity"      : "high",
  "type"          : "error"
}

Hourly_stats:  
{
   "hour"         : "2017O30123" //23rd hour
   incoming_events_during_this_hour : [
        {"event_id" : 1, "received" : 12},
        {"event_id" : 2, "received" : 14}, 
        {"event_id" : 3, "received" : 8},
   ]
}
{
   "hour"         : "2017O30124" //24th hour
   incoming_events_during_this_hour : [
        {"event_id" : 1, "received" : 16},
        {"event_id" : 2, "received" : 14}, 
        {"event_id" : 3, "received" : 8},
   ]
}
```

Expected output is:

```
After Lookup on Events with target collection Hourly_stats
    {
      "event_id"      : "1"
      "event_name"    : "name1",
      "severity"      : "high",
      "type"          : "error"
      incoming_events_during_this_hour : [
              {
               "hour"         : "2017O30123",
               {"event_id" : 1, "received" : 12},
              },
              {
               "hour"         : "2017O30124",
               {"event_id" : 1, "received" : 16},
              }
      ]
    }

OR as multiple rows (per hour basis)

    {
      "event_id"      : "1"
      "event_name"    : "name1",
      "severity"      : "high",
      "type"          : "error"
      incoming_events_during_this_hour : 
              {
               "hour"         : "2017O30123",
               {"event_id" : 1, "received" : 12},
              }
    }


    {
      "event_id"      : "1"
      "event_name"    : "name1",
      "severity"      : "high",
      "type"          : "error"
      incoming_events_during_this_hour : 
              {
               "hour"         : "2017O30124",
               {"event_id" : 1, "received" : 16},
              }
    }
```

Comment: @Blakes Seven pls help.

Comment: Your issue isn't unwind, it's the fact that you have a lot of data and you only want to aggregate some of it.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Yes, you are correct. Actully i want to reduce the burden of $unwind by selecting only few thousands records.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below aggregation for a start.. You will need to add a match on `hour` as it will fetch the entire `Hourly_stats` collection.

The below query unwinds the `incoming_events_during_this_hour` to get the `event id` and  groups the `incoming_events_during_this_hour` for each event and final step is to do lookup for event information.

```
db.Hourly_stats.aggregate([{
    $unwind: "$incoming_events_during_this_hour"
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$incoming_events_during_this_hour.event_id",
        incoming_events_during_this_hour: {
            $push: {
                hour: "$hour",
                "event_received": "$incoming_events_during_this_hour"
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $lookup: {
        "from": "Events",
        "localField": "_id",
        "foreignField": "event_id",
        "as": "_id"
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        event: {
            $arrayElemAt: ["$_id", 0]
        },
        incoming_events_during_this_hour: 1
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Dear Veeram, Thank you!. But what i want is SKIPING $unwind due perf issue. I will update my question. In short I will have 5000 variety of events and every hour; incoming_events_during_this_hour array  will have same (or) less 5000 counters. Now if i do unwind on incoming_events_during_this_hour for 5days will be like 5*24*5000 records has to lookup with 5000 records on events collection. This will make delay processing it. Instead if i would like to $match on Events, like only info events or only Error events, then that will be less than 5000, then for those i want to lkup. wil update Q

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, that's the reason I said you will need a match, but if you want to join from Events collections into embedded event document in Hourly_Stat is not possible as far as I know. You will need to update your Hourly_Stat to move  the event_id to be at the top level. You can always add a match on event id and range on hour on Hourly_Stat and then unwind.

Comment: Yes, All i want is match on (event_id, hour) before doing the $lookup. But problem is both are on different collection. If $lookup accepts new field `$match_on_foreign/$foreignMatch` then my problem will be solved. :)

Comment: There is a open jira https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-25051 to address the problem with `foreignMatch` issue.  As I mentioned before you can't do join from `Event` to `Hourly_stat` because of the embedded array structure so I think for now you may need to do match on `event_id`,` hour` on `Hourly_Stat` collection and use indexes to make that process faster and then unwind and join back to `Event` collection.

Comment: May be i have to do first match query on (5000) Events, and get list of matched event_ids, Then second call to db.Hourly_stats with $aggregate [  {first $match on hour}, {second $match on this event_ids list using $in }, then {$unwind} then {$lookup_foreign_events}]. Cons-Two round trips and $in is costly.

Comment: Thank you! i will follow with that JIRA.

Comment: You are welcome. Yes that is another option for now. yeah test them both n decide.

Comment: If $lookup is followed by $unwind and $match on field inside "as" then the match will get pushed into the $lookup itself.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky I see that is the one of the optimization. Now that we have you here. Do you mind telling us if it possible to $lookup if the foreign field is embedded array like in OP's case ?

Comment: You can match same as with find but you can't return into array anything but full document.  This is complex enough question that it's not really good fit for SO.

Comment: I changed my db and went with aws redshift now.